# Why do we use non-negative functions in measure theory

Tags: measure-theory

I've just started learning Measure theory and I was curious if there is a rationale for working with non-negative functions as the 'base' upon which more complex theorems are built. Why not include negative functions from the onset? Where do we run into trouble?

As this is a pretty general/beginner's question, it would be great if I could get answers which give me an intuitive understanding of the subject.

Thanks!

Comment: Probably, the theorems you see using non-negative functions only don't work for arbitrary functions. In any cases, since a generic function can be easily written as a difference of two non-negative functions, one may as well simplify things and work with non-negative functions only. Also remember that matters of convergence often go through taking an absolute value first (absolute convergence).

Answer (score 4):

The standard machine for proving an identity involving an integral in $L^p$ (especially when that identity involves convergence) is:

1. Is it true for simple functions?
2. Since we can express every function as a limit of simple functions, we consider a nonnegative general function first. This allows us to execute our proof using the Monotone Convergence Theorem or Fatou's lemma, or any other tools that require *f* to be nonnegative. Basically, we can look at a more specialized set of results.
3. Last step, we can write any function $f = f^+ - f^-$. Where $$f^+ = \begin {cases} f, f>0 \\ 0, else  \end {cases}$$ $$f^- = \begin {cases} |f|, f<0 \\ 0, else  \end {cases}$$

By linearity, the result is extended.

A lot of the time (not *all* the time), if something works for nonnegative functions, then it extends to all functions.

Comment: +1. I would add that part of the benefit of isolating step 3 from step 2 is that we can separate issues with "$\infty-\infty$" from everything else.